# Should calls to OututDebugString be wrapped in #ifdef DEBUG conditional blocks?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

In winbase.h I see the following code, marking `OutputDebugStringA/W` as procedures rather than conditional macros. Does this mean it is best to wrap calls to these procedures in debug-only conditional blocks to keep production code tight, especially in tight loops?

```
WINBASEAPI
VOID
WINAPI
OutputDebugStringA(
    __in LPCSTR lpOutputString
    );
WINBASEAPI
VOID
WINAPI
OutputDebugStringW(
    __in LPCWSTR lpOutputString
    );
#ifdef UNICODE
#define OutputDebugString  OutputDebugStringW
#else
#define OutputDebugString  OutputDebugStringA
#endif // !UNICODE
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually we do something like this:

```
#if defined (DEBUG) | defined (_DEBUG)
#define DebugOutput(x) OutputDebugString(x)
#else
#define DebugOutput(x)
#endif
```

`DebugOutput` will be expanded to nothing in release mode, keeping release binary clean and without `#idfef`/`#endif` everywhere in the code.

Note, that it is a good idea to also check if compiler is MSVC (`_MSC_VER`), so your code could be more portable

Comment: What do you mean with checking for compiler is MSVC? `OutputDebugString` in a Windows API function inside kernel32.

Comment: @MicroVirus I think I meant that you'd better check if `OutputDebugString` is available on current platform. I never used it with other compilers (and IDEs) available on Windows (using `stderr` instead). Do you think that there is better variable than `_MSC_VER` to check?

Comment: Well, if you include `windows.h` then it's available, and it doesn't matter which compiler you use (as long as it can target windows). You're right: `_MSC_VER` is the right variable to check for Visual Studio, but checking it isn't equivalent to checking if you are targeting windows (for instance, MinGW).